# ! 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

Tags: r

```
ratiodf<-vedio5 %>% 
  group_by(category) %>% 
  summarise(likes=sum(likes),
            dislikes = sum(dislikes)) %>% 
  mutate(ratio = likes/dislikes)

ggplot(data=ratiodf)+
  geom_col(mapping=aes(x=ratio,y=category))
```

The last line of the code is not working because the data type of the Category column is List. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Hello. Maybe it could help if you do: 'ratiodf$category <- as.character(ratiodf$category) '. In this case you ensure that it's treated as a categorical variable rather than a list.